# Auth0 : Custom Login auth0.webAuth is not a constructor

Tags: php, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

Im using Custom UI login form.

When I tried to call the JavaScript like in the Auth0 documentation. I got the following issue:

```
auth0.webAuth is not a constructor
```

I'm using the latest js file.

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/8.0/auth0.min.js"></script>
var webAuth = new auth0.webAuth({
    domain:         'XXXXX.auth0.com',
    clientID:       'QizVo__XXXXXXXX',
    redirectUri:    'http://localhost/XXXXXXX/callback'
});
```

Its not angular. I just want to use in php and place this code in html.

Just added above js file and jquery as provided by auth0 and load the page I got above message.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `auth0.WebAuth()` with capital W.